# Powershell Check all server for a specific patch

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to use powershell to check all server to see if the patch is installed or if I need to install it.

If I run bits of the code by itself it seems to work but my expected result always assumes that the patch is not installed.

```
#You can change this to find a specific patch
$patch = "KB2550978"
$installed ='no'
#Get all windows server from AD
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$servers = Get-ADComputer -filter {(objectclass -eq "computer") -and (OperatingSystem -like "*Windows Server*")}
# Procces through Servers to find who is missing or has it installed
foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
$hotfixes = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $server.name 
foreach ($hotfix in $hotfixes)
{
If ($hotfix.hotfixid -like $patch)
{

$installed = 'yes'

}

}
if ($installed = 'no')
{
write-host $server.name "does not have $patch installed."
} Else {
Write-Host $server.name "has $patch installed!"
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't done a terribly good job of explaining where the failure is. I will offer this though: since you know you're looking for a specific hotfix, pass that hotfix ID to `get-hotfix` with the `-id` parameter. This will be *much* more efficient than pulling all hotfixes and then searching the list.

Comment: You're still not explaining yourself well.

Comment: The problem I am having is that it will return that the patch is not installed regardless if it is actually installed. I know I can manually see if the patch is installed via the ID parameter 

Can you help with why this it always returns that it is not installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can see where your problem is, you never reset the value of $installed to 'no' so after you find your first 'yes' all consecutive servers become 'yes' too. alroc is right too, much more efficient to check for the particular hotfix rather than iterate through a all. This should do the trick:

```
#You can change this to find a specific patch
$patch = "KB2550978"
#Get all windows server from AD
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$servers = Get-ADComputer -filter {(objectclass -eq "computer") -and (OperatingSystem -like "*Windows Server*")}
# Procces through Servers to find who is missing or has it installed
foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
    $hotfix = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $server.name -Id $patch -ErrorAction 0;  
    if ($hotfix)
    {       
        write-host $server.name "does not have $patch installed."
    } 
    Else {
        Write-Host $server.name "has $patch installed!"
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you!.  You were very helpful. I was looking at the script for so long that the obvious escaped me.

Comment: Isn't there a logic fault in this script? if($hotfix) { "not installed" }

Comment: If `$patch` doesn't exist on target, then `$hotfix = $null`; `if($null)` will result in evaluation to `$false` which is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

There does appear to be a logic fault in the answer. If $hotfix returns the results of Get-Hotfix with a positive result (it found the patch), then "if ($hotfix)" should write the patch IS installed and the Else would be the opposite. I ran the script in my environment after verifying several servers and found the script was returning opposite answers. A simple change to "If (!($hotfix))" does the trick.

Comment: Corrected script:

$patch = "KB2550978"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$servers = Get-ADComputer -filter {(objectclass -eq "computer") -and (OperatingSystem -like "*Windows Server*")}
foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
    $hotfix = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $server.name -Id $patch -ErrorAction 0;  
#### Correction on next line ####
    if (!($hotfix))
    {       
        write-host $server.name "does not have $patch installed."
    } 
    Else {
        Write-Host $server.name "has $patch installed!"
    }   
}